# How to name infix operators?

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```ml
[<AutoOpen>]
module OptionOperators =

    let private mapOption func arg =
           match arg with
           | None -> Ok None
           | Some arg -> func arg |> Result.map Some

    let ( ^> ) arg func =
        mapOption func arg

[<AutoOpen>]
module Model =

    // Constrained to be no more than 35 chars, not null or empty, used for tag
    type String35 = private String35 of string
    module String35 =
        let create field str =
            ConstrainedType.createString field String35 35 str

type UnvalidatedAddress = { Name: string option }
type Address = { Name: String35 option }
let validate dto =
    result {
        let! name = dto.Name ^> String35.create "Name"
    }
```

Is `^>` the reasonable infix operator for the combine of Result and Option?
And is there a list of infix operators?

Answer (score 0):

You're losing readability by using that obscure operator. I suggest you look for something more meaningful that anyone reading your code can understand:

```
let private validateField validator arg =
       match arg with
       | None -> Ok None
       | Some arg -> validator arg |> Result.map Some
```

which you can use as:

```
let validate dto =
    result {
        let! name = dto.Name
                    |>validateField (String35.create "Name")
    }
```

Comment: Your `validate` function is my `mapOption` function. To me, the infix operation is not only clear but also concise.

Comment: @TrungDo if you're the only developer and it's clearer for you that's fine.  I wouldn't have understood it without seeing the definition.    Your translation of Option to Result is rather unusual since both types seem identical.     There are a number of well understood operators in the context of monads but in your example you're changing types from Option to Result.  If everything used Option types then there are a number of handy operators that could be applied to express composition.

Comment: After a few hours of reading I think I should not use an infix operator for this. But the appropriate name for the function is, not `mapOption`, not `validateField`, but `Option.traverseResult` with the signature `('a -> Result<'b, 'c>) -> 'a option -> Result<'b option, 'c>`. References: [https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/) and [https://demystifyfp.gitbook.io/fstoolkit-errorhandling/option/traverseresult](https://demystifyfp.gitbook.io/fstoolkit-errorhandling/option/traverseresult)